# Error using SqlSoup with database views

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to use SqlSoup with an existing database that contains views. Accessing a table goes swimmingly, but accessing a view results in "PKNotFoundError: table '[viewname]' does not have a primary key defined..."

Do I correctly infer that SqlSoup does not work with database views (by default, at least)? I've been unable to find anything directly relevant on Google, SO, or the SqlAlchemy mailing list. If you were faced with this, how would you proceed if you wanted to access non-updatable views? I'm new to SQLAlchemy and SQLSoup.

Here's a specific example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup import SqlSoup
u = SqlSoup('postgresql+psycopg2://PUBLIC@unison-db.org:5432/unison')
seq = u.pseq.filter(u.pseq.pseq_id==76).all() # okay
aliases = u.pseqalias.filter(u.pseqalias.pseq_id==76).all()
```

This is a public database. You can run the equivalent queries using psql:

```
psql -h unison-db.org -U PUBLIC -d unison -c 'select * from pseq where pseq_id=76'
psql -h unison-db.org -U PUBLIC -d unison -c 'select * from pseqalias where pseq_id=76'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Randy for the map() tip.  Here's a complete solution that you may try verbatim (the database is publicly available):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup import SqlSoup
from sqlalchemy import Table
u = SqlSoup('postgresql+psycopg2://PUBLIC@unison-db.org:5432/unison')
pa_t = Table("palias", u._metadata, autoload=True, schema='unison')
pa = u.map(pa_t,primary_key=[pa_t.c.pannotation_id])
pa.slice(0,20).all()
```

This is with Python 2.7.1, Alchemy 0.7.2.

For references, see:

- http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html?highlight=table#sqlalchemy.schema.Table
- http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/sqlsoup.html?highlight=map#sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup.SqlSoup.map

Comment: This is good, but somewhat cryptic to stare at fresh and understand, especially for someone trying to use SqlSoup without being fluent in SqlAlchemy.  I may pick this answer apart for my own situation and then post notes here as a second perspective. This issue persists today in sqlsoup 0.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

From Michael Bayer:

> You would need to pass the columns to be considered part of the
>   primary key to the underlying mapper, using sqlsoup.map_to(), but
>   unfortunately there is not a simple interface for that at the moment,
>   since you need the Table object as well to get at the columns.   So
>   until this interface could be improved, for now it would look like:
>
> metadata = u._metadata t = Table("pseqaliases", metadata,
>   autoload=True)
>
> u.map_to("pseqaliases", selectable=t,
>   mapper_args={"primary_key":[t.c.col1, t.c.col2]})
>
> This is just the "primary_key" argument to mapper, there are some
>   examples at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html near
>   the top.

http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/fc1e8d079e10bac8

I tried the map_to() method but still received the PK error.  The following method, however, worked fine:

```
ss = SqlSoup(db.engine)
meta = ss._metadata
tbl_vrmf = sa.Table("vRMF", meta, autoload=True)
vrmf_pks = [tbl_vrmf.c.dateId, tbl_vrmf.c.ident, tbl_vrmf.c.mnum]
vrmf = ss.map(tbl_vrmf, primary_key=vrmf_pks)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
from sqlalchemy import sql
from sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup import SqlSoup

u = SqlSoup('postgresql+psycopg2://PUBLIC@unison-db.org:5432/unison')

pseq_id = sql.column('pseq_id')
aliases = u.bind.execute(sql.select([pseq_id, '*'], from_obj=['pseqalias'])\
                .where(pseq_id==76)).fetchall()
```

Of course you can do just:

```
aliases = u.bind.execute('select * from pseqalias where pseq_id=76').fetchall()
```

...but in this case you loose reusability.

Comment: Your code works, but the objects don't have column attributes, of course. I was hoping for a model-based interface to a view just as tables have.